# CSS Affect all text before a specific character

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway using CSS to affect all text before a certain character in an element and all text after the character to be unaffected.

```
<p id=janmar class=StrongText>Flowering Time: January to March</p>
```

I want all of the text before and including the ":" to be bold but everything after it to be normal.

```
.StrongText {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I'll probably end up having to split the paragraph into two and use different classes on each but if there is a way then it might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<strong></strong>` tags, like:

```html
<p id="janmar"><strong>Flowering Time</strong>: January to March</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use an inline phrasing element like `<span>`:

```css
p span {
font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Flowering Time:</span> January to March</p>
```

Comment: Excellent! Can't believe I didn't think of this before.

Comment: Note also that `<strong>...</strong>` in HTML5 is intended to semantically mark up **strongly emphasised** text. And then there is `<b>...</b>` which is _also_ valid HTML5 (albeit typographic rather than semantic)... though I'm not sure how that is supposed to differ from a `span` styled as `font-weight: bold;`

Comment: Just checked the notes from W3C - apparently `<b>...</b>` is a _last resort_. Given that `font-weight: bold;` exists and `<span>` exists, I'm not sure I can imagine any use-case for `<b>...</b>`.